# Поймать переход на другую вкладку

Tags: javascript

Есть задача разработать web-приложение для написания сочинения к 9 мая. Сочинение должно писаться по знаниям в голове и без использования поисковых систем. Если пользователь перешел на другую вкладку, то мне нужно очищать форму ввода и писать ошибку о нарушении. Возник вопрос:

**Как поймать действиe, когда пользователь уходит с текущей вкладки (кроссбраузерно и кроссплатформенно)?**

Comment: Что мешает пользователю использовать телефон?) В таком случае лучше запустить веб-камеру и контролировать, что бы ученик смотрел только в монитор)

Comment: Вариант HTML Application не рассматривали?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Чтобы найти информацию в телефоне нужно время. А у пользователя между написанием слов 30 секунд на мысль. Обратите внимание слов, а не букв...он не сможет клацать по клавишам и искать информацию в телефоне

Comment: А как же голосовые помощники?)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko они лишь предлагают ссылки в основном. На открытие и чтение нужно время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По вопросу [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur) / [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) поможет?

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let t = new Date().getTime();

window.onblur = function() {
  document.querySelector('textarea').value = '';
  window.onfocus = focus;
  t = new Date().getTime();
}

function focus() {
  t = new Date().getTime();
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'Вы вернулись, но все уже пропало';
}

draw();

function draw(){
  p.innerHTML = ((new Date().getTime() - t)/1000).toFixed(0);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
```

```html
<span>Если iframe потеряет фокус, все что вы напечатали пропадет</span>
<p></p>
<textarea cols=80 rows=10></textarea >
```

Однако ничего не мешает скопировать содержимое в буфер и потом опять вставить

Comment: Копирование и вставка будут блокироваться

Comment: @ДенисНебесный вот так еще считайте время на странице и еще можно время вне неё считать. а еще это можно на сервер передавать...(обновил ответ)

Comment: А это будет работать на мобильных? Насколько я помню, там блур и фокус не работают.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сейчас проверил на айфоне - таймер обнулился когда вкладку поменял и обратно

Comment: А если свернуть браузер?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну свернёт он браузер, а время ведь будет идти. 30 секунд пройдет и данные сгорят